# React JS context with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-context

I'm creating a simple example in react js using createContext and useState, but I'm doing something wrong, look it:

this is my component categoriacontex.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const CategoriaContext = createContext();

export default CategoriaContext;
```

this's component types.js

```
export const GET_CATEGORIAS = "GET_CATEGORIAS";
```

this's component categoriasreducer.js

```
import { GET_CATEGORIAS } from "../types";

export default (state, action) => {
  const { payload, type } = action;
;
  switch (type) {
    case GET_CATEGORIAS:
      return {
        ...state,
        categorias: payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

this's component categoriastate.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CategoriaContext from './CategoriaContext';
import CategoriaReducer from './CategoriasReducer';
import Data from '../../Data/Categorias.json';
import { GET_CATEGORIAS } from "../types";

const CategoriaState = (props) => {

    const initialState = {
        categorias: [],
        selectedCategoria: null,
      };
    
    
    const [state, setstate] = useState(CategoriaReducer, initialState);

    const GetCategorias = () => {
        try { 
           setstate({ type: GET_CATEGORIAS, payload: Data });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } 
    };

    return(         
        <CategoriaContext.Provider
                    value={{ 
                            categorias: state.categorias
                    }}                 
        >
            {props.children}
        </CategoriaContext.Provider> 
    )
  
};

export default CategoriaState;
```

this one is component app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Component/Header/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import CategoriaState from './Context/Categorias/CategoriaState';
import AddCat from './Component/Categorias/AddCat';
import Allcat from './Component/Categorias/AllCat';

class App extends Component {
  
   
  render(){
    return(
      <CategoriaState>
        <div className="container">        
          <Router>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">             
                <h1>home</h1>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/addcat">
                <AddCat />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/allcat">
                <Allcat />
              </Route>            
            </Switch>
          </Router> 
        </div>
      </CategoriaState>      
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this's componente allcat.js

```
import React, { useEffect }  from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import CategoriaContext from '../../Context/Categorias/CategoriaContext';

const AllCat = () => {

    const { categorias, GetCategorias }  = useContext( CategoriaContext );

    useEffect(() => {
        GetCategorias();
        
    },[])

    return(
        <div className="container mx-auto">
            <div className="card col-md-5 mx-auto">
                <h4 className="card-title text-center px-0 mx-0 border-bottom">Categorias</h4>            
                <div className="card-body px-0">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

};

export default AllCat;
```

I know that I have some errors, because this is my first example using context in react js, I wan't is create a simple crud using context and hook, I have a file data, this file is call Data, this file have an id, description, idfather.

so please, do you can help me, the better way to work with context and usestate??

Answer (score 1):

In categoriastate.js you don't set the GetCategorias member of the Provider's value, so you will only access the categorias from `useContext( CategoriaContext )` and the GetCategorias will be undefined (in allcat.js).

Comment: I get it! I solved myself. But I have another question, I'l post a new questions. thanks!